# Contact Form Not Posting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, contact-form

I'm having trouble getting a form to post. The code i'm using was adapted from a much simpler form i've used in the past. I've tried to adopt the .js and .php to work with the new form, but when i click "submit" nothing happens.

The form has some ant-spam things added including adding the form's action after the submit button is clicked. On the original, simple form, this works perfectly, but on the new one, nothing happens when submit is pressed.

The form with the problems can be seen [here](http://kkglass.com/agents2.php)

The simple form that was derived from can be seen [here](http://kkglass.com/testing/index.html)

Can anyone see what i'm missing here? I assume i'll find more issues as well, but right now i'm focusing on trying to get the form to post.

Any insight or information is really REALLY appreciated!

Thank you all,
Jason

**Edit**
Sorry for the noob post without code guys... here it is:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form role="ajaxExample" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="agents">
          <div id="response"></div>
          <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Customer Information:</strong></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><strong>Vehicle Information:</strong></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                    <input type="text" name="cusName" id="cusName">
              </td>
              <td><label for="year">Year:</label></td>
              <td>
                <select name="year" id="year" tabindex="9">
                  <option value="">Select Year...</option>
<?php
                  for ($x = date("Y") + 1; $x >= 1962; $x--)  
                  {

                      echo '<option value="'.$x.'"'.'>'.$x."</option>";

                  }                 
?>                  
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="address">Address:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="cusAddress" id="cusAddress" /></td>
              <td><label for="make">Make:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="make" id="make" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="city">City:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" /></td>
              <td><label for="model">Model:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="model" id="model" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="state">State:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="state" id="state" /></td>
              <td><label for="bodyStyle">Body Style:</label></td>
              <td>
                <select name="bodyStyle" id="bodyStyle">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
                  <option value="2 Door">2 Door</option>
                  <option value="4 Door">4 Door</option>
                  <option value="Wagon">Wagon</option>
                  <option value="Hatchback">Hatchback</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="zip">Zip Code:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" /></td>
              <td><label for="vin">VIN Number:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="vin" id="vin" maxlength="17" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="homePhone">Home Phone:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="homePhone" id="homePhone" /></td>
              <td><label for="damagedGlass">Damaged Glass:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="damagedGlass" id="damagedGlass" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="workPhone">Work Phone:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="workPhone" id="workPhone" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="cellPhone">Cell Phone:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="cellPhone" id="cellPhone" /></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Insurance Information:</strong></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="insCompany">Ins. Company:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="insCompany" id="insCompany" /></td>
              <td><label for="agency">Agency</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="agency" id="agency" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="policy">Policy#:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="policy" id="policy" /></td>
              <td><label for="sentBy">Sent By:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="sentBy" id="sentBy" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="compCoverage">Comp. Coverage:</label></td>
              <td><input type="radio" name="compCoverage" id="compCoverage" value="YES" />&nbsp;Yes&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="compCoverage" id="compCoverage" /></td>
              <td><label for="deductible">Deductible:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="deductible" id="deductible" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="dateOfLoss">Date Of Loss:</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="dateOfLoss" id="dateOfLoss" /></td>
              <td><label for="causeOfLoss">Cause Of Loss</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="causeOfLoss" id="causeOfLoss" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="right"><label for="replyEmail">Reply Email Address:</label></td>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="replyEmail" id="replyEmail" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><label for="specialInstructions">Are There Any Special Instructions?</label></td>
              <td colspan="2"><textarea name="specialInstructions" id="specialInstructions" cols="38" rows="6"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" name="honeypot" id="honeypot" value="http://"></td>
              <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" name="humancheck" id="humanCheck" class="clear" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="4" align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit Claim</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form"/></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
</body>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ajax_submit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#agents input:submit').click(function() {
        $('#agents form').attr('action', 'http://' + document.domain + '/php/feedback.php');
        $('#agents form').submit();
    });

    $('form #response').hide();
    $('form #nameResponse').hide();
    $('form #phoneResponse').hide();
    $('form #emailResponse').hide();
    $('form #messageResponse').hide();
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {

        // prevent forms default action until
        // error check has been performed
        e.preventDefault();

        // grab form field values
        var valid = '';
        var nameResponse = '';
        var addressResponse = '';
        var cityResponse = '';
        var stateResponse = '';
        var zipResponse = '';
        var phoneResponse = '';

        var yearReponse = '';
        var makeResponse = '';
        var modelResponse = '';
        var bodyStyleResponse = '';
        var vinResponse = '';
        var damagedGlassResponse = '';

        var insCompanyResponse = '';
        var agencyResponse = '';
        var policyResponse = '';
        var sentByResponse = '';
        var compCoverageResponse = '';
        var deductibleResponse = '';
        var dateOfLossResponse = '';
        var causeOfLossResponse = '';
        var replyEmailResponse = '';
        var specialInstructionsResponse = '';


        var required = ' is required.';

        //Custom Information
        var name = $('form #cusName').val();
        var address = $('form #cusAddress').val();
        var city = $('form #city').val();
        var state = $('form #state').val();
        var zip = $('form #zip').val();
        var homePhone = $('form #homePhone').val();
        var workPhone = $('form #workPhone').val();
        var cellPhone = $('form #cellPhone').val();

        //Vehicle Information
        var year = $('form #year').val();
        var make = $('form #make').val();
        var model = $('form #model').val();
        var bodyStyle = $('form #bodyStyle').val();
        var vin = $('form #vin').val();
        var damageGlass = $('form #damagedGlass').val();

        //Insurance Information
        var insCompany = $('form #insCompany').val();
        var agency = $('form #agency').val();
        var policy = $('form #policy');
        var sentBy = $('form #sentBy');
        var compCoverage = $('form #compCoverage').val();
        var deductible = $('form #deductible').val();
        var dateOfLoss = $('form #dateOfLoss').val();
        var causeOfLoss = $('form #causeOfLoss').val();
        var replyEmail = $('form #replyEmail').val();
        var specialInstructions = $('form #specialInstructions').val();

        //Spam Info
        var honeypot = $('form #honeypot').val();
        var humanCheck = $('form #humanCheck').val();

        // perform error checking
        //Customer
        if (name = '' || name.length <= 2) {
            nameResponse += '<p>Customer name' + required +'</p>';  
        }
        if (address = '' || address.length <= 5) {
            addressResponse += '<p>Customer address' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (city = '' || city.length <=2) {
            cityResponse += '<p>Customer city' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (state = '' || state.length < 2) {
            stateResponse += '<p>Customer state' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (zip = '' || zip.length <= 4) {
            zipResponse += '<p>Customer zip code' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (homePhone = '' || homePhone.length < 7) {
            phoneResponse += '<p>Customer home phone' + required + '</p>';
        }

        //Vehicle
        if (year = '' || year.length < 4) {
            yearResponse += '<p>Vehicle year (ex: 2011)' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (make = '' || make.length <=2) {
            makeResponse += '<p>Vehicle make' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (model = '' || model.length < 2) {
            modelResponse += '<p>Vehicle model' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (bodyStyle = '') {
            bodyStyleReponse += '<p>Please select a body style</p>';
        }
        if (vin = '' || vin.length <= 16) {
            vinResponse += '<p>Vin number' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (damagedGlass = '' || damagedGlass <= 3) {
            damagedGlassResponse += '<p>Damaged Glass' + required + '</p>';
        }

        //Insurance 
        if (insCompany = '' || insCompany.length <=2) {
            insCompanyResponse += '<p>Insurance company' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (agency = '' || agency.length <=3) {
            agencyResponse += '<p>Agency' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (policy = '' || policy.length <=5) {
            policyResponse += '<p>Policy number' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (sentBy = '' || sentBy.length <= 6) {
            sentByResponse += '<p>Please include your name in the ' + '"Sent By"' + 'field</p>';
        }
        if (compCoverage = '') {
            compCoverage += '<p>Comp Coverage' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (deductible = '') {
            deductibleResponse += '<p>Deductible' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (dateOfLoss = '' || dateOfLoss.length <= 3) {
            dateOfLoss += '<p>Date of loss' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (causeOfLoss = '' || causeOfLoss.length <= 3) {
            causeOfLoss += '<p>Cause of loss' + required + '</p>';
        }
        if (!replyEmail.match(/^([a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9._-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$)/i)) {
            replyEmailResponse += '<p>Your reply email' + required +'</p>';                                               
        }
        if (specialInstructions = '' || specialInstructions.length <= 5) {
            specialInstructionsResponse += '<p>A message' + required + '</p>';  
        }   

        if (honeypot != 'http://') {
            valid += '<p>Spambots are not allowed.</p>';    
        }
        if (humanCheck != '') {
            valid += '<p>A human user' + required + '</p>'; 
        }

    // let the user know if there are erros with the form

        if (valid != '') {


            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                    '<strong>Please correct the errors below.</strong>' + '</div>'
                            ).fadeIn('fast');

            if (nameResponse != '') {
                    $('form #nameResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            nameResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (addressResponse != '') {
                    $('form #addressResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            addressResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (cityResponse != '') {
                    $('form #cityResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            cityResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (stateResponse != '') {
                    $('form #stateResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            stateResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (zipResponse != '') {
                    $('form #zipResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            zipResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (phoneResponse != '') {
                    $('form #phoneResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            phoneResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }

            if (yearResponse != '') {
                    $('form #yearResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            yearResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (makeResponse != '') {
                    $('form #makeResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            makeResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (modelResponse != '') {
                    $('form #modelResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            modelResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (bodyStyleResponse != '') {
                    $('form #addressResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            bodyStyleResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (vinResponse != '') {
                    $('form #vinResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            vinResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (damagedGlassResponse != '') {
                    $('form #damagedGlassResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            damagedGlassResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }

            if (insCompanyResponse != '') {
                    $('form #insCompanyResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            insCompanyResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (agencyResponse != '') {
                    $('form #agencyResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            agencyResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (policyResponse != '') {
                    $('form #policyResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            policyResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (sentByResponse != '') {
                    $('form #sentByResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            sentByResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (compCoverageResponse != '') {
                    $('form #compCoverageResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            compCoverageResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (deductibleResponse != '') {
                    $('form #deductibleResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            deductibleResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (dateOfResponse != '') {
                    $('form #dateOfResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            dateOfResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (causeOfResponse != '') {
                    $('form #causeOfResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            causeOfResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (replyEmailResponse != '') {
                    $('form #replyEmailResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            replyEmailResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
            if (specialInstructionsResponse != '') {
                    $('form #specialInstructionsResponse').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+
                            specialInstructionsResponse + '</div>'
                                ).fadeIn('fast');
            }
        }
        // let the user know something is happening behind the scenes
        // serialize the form data and send to our ajax function
        else {

            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('fast');                                      

            var formData = $('form').serialize();

            submitForm(formData);           

        }

    });

});

function submitForm(formData) {
    $.ajax({

        type:           'POST',
        url:            'php/feedback.php',
        data:           formData,
        dataType:   'json',
        cache:      false,
        timeout:    7000,
        success:    
        function(data) {
            //we are getting data.error (from ajax, which is formData) and data.msg from our feedback.php
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error':'success')
                                        .html(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');
            if ($('form #response').hasClass('success')) {
                setTimeout ("$('form #response').fadeOut('fast')",5000);
            }
        },
        error: 
        function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' +
                            '<p>There was an <strong>' + errorThrown + 
                                    '</strong> error due to a <strong>' + textStatus +
                                        '</strong> condition.</p>' +
                                            '</div>').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, status) {
            $('form') [0].reset();
        }



    });
};
```

PHP:

```
    <?php 
sleep(.5);
//Sanitize incoming data and create variables
$name = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'])));           

...

$humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
$honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];

if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) { 

        //Validate data and return success or error message
        $error_message = '';    
        $reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,4}$/";

        if (!preg_match($reg_exp, $email)) {

                    $error_message .= "<p>A valid email address is required.</p>";             
        }
        if (empty($name)) {

                    $error_message .= "<p>Please provide your name.</p>";              
        }           
        if (empty($message)) {

                    $error_message .= "<p>A message is required.</p>";
        }       
        if (!empty($error_message)) {
                    $return['error'] = true;
                    $return['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'."<h4>Oops! The request was successful but your form is not filled out correctly.</h4>".$error_message;                  
                    echo json_encode($return);
                    exit();
        } 

        else {
            //mail variables
            ...

            //send email and return a message to user
            if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {  
                $return['error'] = false;
                $return['msg'] = 
                    '<div class="alert alert-success">'.
                        "<h4>Thank you for using our form ".$sentBy ."</h4>".
                        "<p>We'll reply to you at ".$email." as soon as we can.</p>";

                        echo json_encode($return);
            }
            else {

                $return['error'] = true;
                $return['msg'] = "<h4>Oops! There was a problem sending the email. Please try again.</h4>"; 
                echo json_encode($return);
            }

        }

} 
else {

    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = "<h4>Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.</h4>";  
    echo json_encode($return);
}

?>
```

Comment: We can't know where the problem is if you don't post some code.

Comment: As @markz mentioned, your php code is not visible to us like this. Furthermore, it is always recommended to post your code in your question so it can be used for other users with the same problem in the future, incase your website goes down or changes.

Comment: My bad guys, very noob of me. Edits made to include code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your JavaScript. You wrote the variable name `yearReponse` instead of `yearResponse`. Check your error console while you are developing w/ JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks i'll be sure to check that more thoroughly.

Comment: That solved the majority of my problems! Thanks for pointing that out Wayne,

Comment: I'd like the #response div to have focus when the form is submitted. I tried adding [CODE]onsubmit="$('form #response').focus()"[/CODE] to the form, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Any thoughts?